# Can I park here?

Tags: logical-deduction

Help! I visit my mom tomorrow (Tuesday). This parking spot is right across from her house. But when the heck can I and can't I park there??

[image: see CaptainCaption]

[ ------ Automatically generated photo description by CaptainCaption 2.0, copyright OttoEye, GmbH, 2022: ------

Three poles with numerous parking signs in front of a fenced park in the background. The signs read as follows:

**First pole:**

bylaw #o-77(rev2) not in effect 15:15 - 15:44.  —bylaw #p-200001

bylaw #r-100t: parking prohibited 14:00 - 15:59

according to bylaw #f-0008: bylaw #g-111117bis not in effect

bylaw #s-95.12: bylaw #q-50 not in effect 15:30 - 15:59

rush hour lasts an hour longer on days whose names have "u" in them  —bylaw #b-1399

bylaw #m-19min: all bylaws in effect unless stated otherwise

obey bylaws

bylaw #i-forty: all bylaws declaring single bylaws not in effect are not in effect the first 10 mins of every hour

**Second pole:**

bylaw #q-50: bylaw #r-100t not in effect 15:00 - 15:59

bylaw #q-50 not in effect  —bylaw #o-77(rev2)

bylaw #n-68: parking prohibited in the a.m.

bylaw #b-1399 not in effect 18:45 - 19:14  —bylaw #a-757

parking prohibited during rush hour  —bylaw #g-111117bis

rush hour starts an hour earlier on fridays  —bylaw #k-9904

bylaw #d-6 not in effect during odd-numbered hours (01:00 - 01:59, etc.)  —bylaw #j-13(3).

**Third pole:**

bylaw #t-18.1.1: bylaw #s-95.12 not in effect 15:45 - 16:59

bylaw #h-80: rush hour is 15:30 - 18:29

violators subject to minimum fine of $500, towing, and/or impoundment  —bylaw #u-333.

bylaw #e-619-0: bylaw #f-0008 not in effect weekdays

warning! bylaw #c-9901 states: bylaw #d-6 not in effect when bylaw #n-68 applicable

bylaw #l-max20: parking permitted unless otherwise prohibited

caution

bylaw #d-6: all bylaws prohibiting parking are not in effect during even-numbered hours   e.g. 14:00 - 14:59

------ Automatically generated photo description by CaptainCaption 2.0, copyright OttoEye, GmbH, 2022. ------]

Comment: Try it out! The council of totems with funny inscriptions will decide your fate...

Comment: I suggest taking the bus

Comment: Blocking out the scenery, Messing with my mind!

Comment: Accept thy fate. Welcome to Chance Time: Parking Edition.

Comment: Interesting puzzle. I found a contradiction I can't resolve though. Bylaw N-68 states "Parking prohibited in the A.M." Bylaw D-6 states "All bylaws prohibiting parking are not in effect during even numbered hours". So I would be able to park at 10:00am say. However, bylaw C-9901 states "bylaw D-6 not in effect when bylaw N-68 applicable". So is N-68 applicable at 10 am or not? Without D-6 it is applicable at 10 am, with D-6 it is not applicable. But D-6 is not in effect due to C-9901. Whichever bylaw you enforce first wins, but we can't choose which one to do first, so it's a contradiction.

Comment: @Amorydai I interpreted that as meaning that D-6 is not applicable during the AM when N-68 applies. (And that's all before you start applying i-forty.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're gonna have to move your car a few times during your visit. For Tuesday, the hours you can safely park your car are:

> 00:00-00:09; 2:00-2:09; 4:00-4:09; 6:00-6:09; 8:00-8:09; 10:00-10:09; 12:00-14:59; 15:15-15:29; 16:00-16:59; 18:00-18:59; 19:10-19:14; 19:30-23:59.

> First thing I did was categorize the bylaws. The bylaws prohibiting parking are: R-100T; N-68; G-111117BIS.

> The bylaws categorizing the rush hour are: H-80; B-1399; K-9904.

> The bylaws declaring a single bylaw not in effect are: P-200001; F-0008; S-95.12; Q-50; O-77; A-757; J-13(3); T-18.1.1; E-619-0; C-9901.

> The bylaws that are pretty much always active, unless otherwise stated: I-FORTY; D-6.

> The common sense bylaws that are not relevant to this problem: M-19MIN; U-333; L-MAX20.

> Ok, well, let's start with I-FORTY. All bylaws declaring single bylaws not in effect are not in effect the first 10 mins of every hour. This leaves D-6 to be active, which means you are allowed to park on the first 10 minutes of every even hour. (00:00-00:09; 2:00-2:09; 4:00-4:09; 6:00-6:09; 8:00-8:09; 10:00-10:09)

> J-13(3) states D-6 is not in effect during odd numbered hours, which it doesn't effect anyway, so we can throw this one out. N-68 states parking prohibited in A.M. and C-9901 states bylaw D-6 is not in effect when bylaw N-68 is applicable. When dealing with bureaucrats you can bet they will choose to screw you whenever they can, so I'll assume the more strict interpretation that D-6 is not effective in the whole of A.M. when N-68 is applicable. This means you cannot park until noon at all, except in the first 10 minutes of every even hour, as I've already described.

> Next solve the bylaws regarding R-100T. These are: P-200001; Q-50; O-77; S-95.12; T-18.1.1. O-77 says Q-50 is not in effect. However, P-200001 says O-77 is not in effect 15:15-15:44. This means Q-50 is only in effect 15:15-15:44. Next S-95.12 states Q-50 is not in effect 15:30-15:59, which means Q-50 is now only in effect 15:15-15:29. T-18.1.1 states S-95.12 is not in effect 15:45-16:59 which doesn't mean anything as Q-50 is already not in effect after 15:45 due to O-77 so we can disregard this one. Q-50 states R-100T is not in effect 15:00-15:59, but as Q-50 is only active 15:15-15:29 as I've already stated, it can only have an effect during those times, so parking is allowed 15:15-15:29.

> Next look at E-619-0, it states F-0008 is not in effect on weekdays. As you're parking on a Tuesday, which is a weekday, this means both E-619-0 and F-0008 may be disregarded as they don't add any more value.

> Last tangle is A-757 which deals with rush hour. First let's define the rush hour, K-9904 talks about Friday, which is irrelevant as it is Tuesday. B-1399 states the rush hour is 1 hour longer on days that have a "u" in them, which Tuesday does, so according to H-80 the rush hour is 15:30-18:29 but now it is 15:30-19:29. A-757 states B-1399 is not in effect 18:45-19:14. Rush hour thus becomes 15:30-18:44 and 19:15-19:29. However, because of I-FORTY, A-757 is not in effect the first 10 minutes of every hour. This makes the rush hour 15:30-18:44; 19:00-19:09; 19:15-19:29.

> Finally, D-6 is not hampered by any bylaws after the A.M. so you can park on any even numbered hour (12:00-12:59; 14:00-14:59; 16:00-16:59; 18:00-18:59; 20:00-20:59; 22:00-22:59)

> Putting it all together: due to N-68 no parking is allowed in the A.M. except the first 10 minutes of every even hour (D-6). Due to R-100T, no parking is allowed 14:00-15:59, except 14:00-14:59 (D-6) and 15:15-15:29 (Q-50). Due to G-11111BIS and B-1399, no parking is allowed 15:30-19:29 except 16:00-16:59 and 18:00-18:59 (D-6) and 19:10-19:14 (A-757). Parking is allowed after rush hour ends 19:30 onward.